# GoogleCredentials reference not resolved with existing dependencies

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, access-token, android-security

In my ongoing attempt to securely create and use Oauth 2 tokens, I'm now trying to get the token via the following code:

```
private static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
    GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream("service-account.json"))
            .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
    googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken();
    return googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
}
```

However, GoogleCredentials isn't resolved. What dependency do I need to add to my app gradle file to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.2.2
implementation platform(com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2)

implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

latest dependence

```
implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.3.0'
```

official doc link

```
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java
```